# can a brand new car battery cause my alternator to fail?

Tags: battery, alternator

My battery cavity filled with rain water due to a leak in my tail light of my 328i bmw wagon, and when my mechanic replaced the battery he said the new one was putting out too may amps and then fried the alternator. Is this really a thing?

Comment: Hi James and welcome. Worded like that, no. Batteries don't force amps through an alternator.

Comment: That sounds like "technical Bu**sh1t" to baffle customers... Find a garage or place with a decent auto-electrician and get a proper test done.

Comment: the battery put out too many amps for the alternator and it blew the alternator? LOL. its the other way around if anything.

Comment: What year is it and was the battery coded to the PCM when it was installed if it had to be?

Answer (score 1):

The alternator puts amps into the battery, not the other way around... Unless he is talking about the voltage regulator, I guess you could blow that up but not really sure how likely that is in any shorting situation. Might have been a bad hookup attempt.

Is the alternator not working at all or is it just really really weak?

Its possible that having a dead battery caused your already worn out alternator to work harder full-time (a running car can continue to operate on just the alternator and no battery, although not electrically recommended) so that may have worn out the alternator during the (short) time you were running it like that.
If that happened, then more than likely you can just have the alternator rebuilt for much cheaper than buying another unit.

If the voltage regulator is blown, then depending on the car/alternator you can either replace just the regulator on the alternator, or you might have to replace the whole alternator, or you might have to replace the ECU.

Comment: The alternator fuse should blowout if the battery and the other loads draw too much current